# How many instance can I add during Free Google Cloud Trial?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am already running an f1-micro instance on my $300 Google Cloud free trial account, I want to add another site/instance to it.

1. So will it cost me extra or the charges will be deducted from my $300 credit?
2. If I choose a small plan, then the amount will be deducted from my credit? or I have to pay extra for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the free trial, the following limitations apply to your Compute Engine resources:

- Your project can have no more than 8 cores (or virtual CPUs) running at the same time. To run more than 8 vCPUs at a time, you must upgrade your account.
- You cannot add GPUs to your Compute Engine instances.

So answering your questions:

1. The charges will be deducted from your $300 credit
2. The amount will be deducted from your credit. Once the credit is exceeded you will have to pay extra.

**Note**: The micro instance is free even after you use up your credit

Comment: The micro instance is free even after you use up your credit.

Comment: Thanks. Updated the answer.